# Trying to translate "Mastery Through Hardwork"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

I have looked at the following, i'm interested if there is something closer.
"per ardua ad peritiam" -> "through the arduous to the skill."
"dominium in labore" -> "mastery in work" or "dominion through labor."